# Core ASP.NET Project Azure Build Pipeline

Tags: asp.net, build, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a simple solution that have two projects in it and I want it go through the azure build pipeline. One project is pure class files that will get build a DLL but that code is not the GIT repo in the same folder. And the other project is ASP.NET project and I have configured that in the pipeline. When I am trying to build the project it is giving me an error as below:

> MSBUILD : error MSB1011: Specify which project or solution file to use
>   because this folder contains more than one project or solution file.
>   [error]Cmd.exe exited with code '1'.

**Yaml File**

```
# ASP.NET Core
# Build and test ASP.NET Core projects targeting .NET Core.
# Add steps that run tests, create a NuGet package, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core

trigger:
- master

pool:
  name: 'buildserver'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- script: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say your .dll project is "not the GIT repo in the same folder"? This project is not in the same git repository as the asp.net project?

Comment: folder1\solution-1
folder1\project-1

folder2\solution-2
folder2\project-2
folder2\project-1 => referring project-1 

so now this solution is having two projects but I want the build server to run only one

Comment: You say that you have `configured [the asp.net] project in your pipeline`. However, there is nothing in your **YAML** that indicates a project or solution file that should be built (which is what the error is telling you). If you don't specify a project or solution to `dotnet build` it looks for one itself using the current directory. When this pipeline runs that task, your current directory is at the root of the repo.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by `but that code is not the GIT repo in the same folder`. Maybe you can edit your question with a screenshot or text example of what your complete folder structure looks like.

Answer (score 1):

The error is asking you to identify the `.sln` or `.csproj` (or other proj type) file b/c `dotnet` doesn't know what you want it to do.

I tend to use variables for this kind of thing because I'm often using the solution name in other tasks.

### example:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  name: 'buildserver'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  slnName: 'mySol'
  solution: 'some/dir/$(slnName).sln'

steps:
- script: dotnet build $(solution) --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'
```

### .csproj example:

With a repository (and solution) structure as follows:
*(this is the part of your question that remains unclear)*

```
myRepo
|--.git
|--src
   |--proj1
   |  |--proj1.csproj
   |
   |--proj2
   |  |--proj2.csproj
   |
   |--mySol.sln
```

You would simply call out the `.csproj` file you want the pipeline to build.

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  name: 'buildserver'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  projName: 'proj1'
  project: 'src/$(projName)/$(projName).csproj'

steps:
- script: dotnet build $(project) --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'
```

With the above examples you shouldn't need to specify the `.sln` or `.csproj` as each potential build target lives in its own directory, and the dotnet cli searches from `$pwd` if you don't give it a value. Therefore, if your pipeline is working in the root of the repo (default behavior), `dotnet` should find the `.sln` file first and build it.

### However

If your directory structure looks like the following, then you would need to specify:

```
myRepo
|--.git
|--src
   |--proj1.csproj
   |--class1.cs
   |--class2.cs
   |--proj2
   |  |--proj2.csproj
   |  |--class1.cs
   |
   |--mySol.sln
```

In the above `dotnet` doesn't know whether you want to build `mySol.sln` or `proj1.csproj`, so indicating the file to build should solve your problem, but I might suggest that you restructure your repository.

### If `proj2` doesn't make its home in `myRepo`

And is a dependency of `proj1` then you will need to do some other acrobatics (ie: manual git repo clone) in the pipeline to get that project and it's files where they need to be. If this is the case, I would **strongly suggest** you treat `proj2` as a **completely independent** product and deliver it to those projects (`proj1`) that depend upon it via NuGet or other package delivery method.

Comment: I got that but I have only one solution and two projects that solution, how can we mention about our project file?

Comment: Not sure why you would want to not build the `.sln` but if you do, just specify the path to the project file relative to your repository root directory: `variables: proj: 'some/dir/projDir/proj.csproj` and use the variable in the build script as I've indicated.